# Is PRI still the dominant political party in Mexico?

Tags: mexico

I was listening to a podcast that described how since the mid twentyth century the Partido Revolucionario Institucional (PRI) has been there defacto single political party in Mexico. However this recap did not extend until modern day.

Is the PRI still the defacto single political party in Mexico? Not just at the federal, but also at the state and local level. Does modern Mexico have competing parties that have any actual sway?

Comment: You can see on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_Revolutionary_Party that PRI has few seats currently. It's not clear to me what your last question is.

Comment: Some people think Mexico is ran by drug cartels or Carlos Slim (hence the name Slimlandia). Is that what your last question is about?

Comment: Intuitively this question could be easily answered by just [looking up the results of the 2018 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Mexican_general_election). But I can hardly believe that you would ask such a trivially googleable question. Do you have some reason to believe that the last election does not accurately represent the true balance of power of the Mexican political landscape?

Answer (score 3):

I would no longer say "the dominant force", but still "a major force."  After [losing the elections in 2000 to the Conservative PAN party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_general_election,_2000), they managed to win the presidency in 2012.  They are still one of the bigger political parties due to their history in power.  They have ebbed in power since the [2018 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Mexican_general_election), but seeing as many analysts expected the party to collapse after 2000 election, I would say it is too early to call for its demise.  I think it still has a strong base of supporters within the general populace, government and certainly within Mexican business.

It doesn't appear that it is going to collapse as the Communist Parties did in Eastern Europe, but its support could continue to erode as many of the mainstream European political parties have.  Most of these have continued to dominate in some form or fashion as I expect the PRI to as well, but in a less dominant fashion.

Comment: Shorter answer: No. It is no longer a dominant party (a political science term that means a party that always wins almost every political prize of consequence every time, even though other political parties are legally allowed as distinguished from a one party system in which other political parties are legally forbidden). Similarly, the Democratic party in the American Southeast used to be a dominant party but no longer is, and many parties that bring about a nation's independence or regime change are dominant parties until the "honeymoon" wears off often decades later.